# c++ assignment operator= overloading with derived classes

Tags: c++, list, operator-overloading, derived-class, assignment-operator

I'm currently writing a complicated class and in it I basically need to copy a list of derived classes. The simplified version is, as follows:
I have a base class from which I derive several other classes:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void test(void)
    {
        cout << "Base" << endl;
    }
    Base(vector<Base*> *pointer)
    {
        pointer->push_back(this);
    }
    virtual Base& operator=(const Base& rhs)
    {
        cout << "Base=" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};
class A : public Base
{
public:
    void test(void)
    {
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }
    A(vector<Base*> *pointer) : Base(pointer) {}
    A& operator=(const A& rhs)
    {
        cout << "A=" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};
class B : public Base
{
public:
    void test(void)
    {
        cout << "B" << endl;
    }
    B(vector<Base*> *pointer) : Base(pointer) {}
    B& operator=(const B& rhs)
    {
        cout << "B=" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Then I create a list of objects, which I save in the in a pointer list of the Base class:

```
vector<Base*> listA;

new Base(&listA);
new A(&listA);
new B(&listA);
```

These objects I then want to copy in a second list with the same classes (same order), but which might have different values.

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)listA.size(); i++)
{
    (*listA[i]) = (*listB[i]);
}
```

However c++ is not able to do that. Because the list has the type Base*, dereferencing creates an object of type Base. Therefore the assignment operator= of the Base class is called instead of the correct one from the derived class. How can I fix this?

Or how can I tell c++ to use the right operator? Maybe by some isinstanceof-function?

For a full sample see:

```
int main()
{
    vector<Base*> listA;

    new Base(&listA);
    new A(&listA);
    new B(&listA);

    vector<Base*> listB;

    new Base(&listB);
    new A(&listB);
    new B(&listB);


    for (int i = 0; i < (int)listA.size(); i++)
    {
        (*listA[i]).test();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)listA.size(); i++)
    {
        (*listA[i]) = (*listB[i]);
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Base
A
B
Base=
Base=
Base=
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a derived class use the base class operator= (assignment operator)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838211/why-doesnt-a-derived-class-use-the-base-class-operator-assignment-operator?rq=1)

Comment: What does it mean to assign an `A` to a `B` or vice-versa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few misunderstandings here. First and foremost, what does it mean to assign an instance of a derived class to an instance of a base class? Let's take a simple hierarchy:

```
struct A { int x; };
struct B : A { int y; };

A a;
B b;
a = b; // what should this do?
b = a; // what about this?
```

With normal C++, the first one does [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/2069064), and the second one is ill-formed. But even the first one, well well-formed, is typically not what you want to do anyway. Are you *sure* you want to be slicing?

---

The second is that while you made your assignment operator virtual:

```
virtual Base& operator=(const Base& rhs)
```

None of the derived classes actually override it. `A`'s assignment operator takes an `A const&` and `B`'s takes a `B const&`. If you marked the two with `override`, your compiler would point this out to you. If you fix those two to take a `Base const&` argument, then you would get what you want printed - but it's probably still not what you actually want to have happen.

---

In order to actually make polymorphic copies, a typical solution is to provide a virtual clone method:

```
virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
```

That your derived classes implement:

```
struct A : Base {
    A* clone() const override { return new A(*this); }
};
```

And then use `clone()` instead of assignment. There will be no slicing here.

---

Insert the usual caveats about memory management and raw pointers here.

Comment: Thanks! I understand what you are saying. Only the last part I can't wrap my head around. How would I use this clone function in practice?

Comment: You mean by completely replacing the old object? Unfortunately that is not an option!

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I found a solution for my problem. I implemented a copy function which takes the Base class as the argument. Inside this copy function I can copy the variables using the `pointa`. The classe now are as follows:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void test(void)
    {
        cout << "Base" << endl;
    }
    Base(vector<Base*> *pointer)
    {
        pointer->push_back(this);
    }
    virtual void clone(Base* pointer) = 0;
};
class A : public Base
{
public:
    void test(void)
    {
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }
    A(vector<Base*> *pointer) : Base(pointer) {}
    void clone(Base* pointer) override
    {
        A* pointa = (A*)pointer;
        cout << "clone A" << endl;
        //Clone Variables here
    }
};
class B : public Base
{
public:
    void test(void)
    {
        cout << "B" << endl;
    }
    B(vector<Base*> *pointer) : Base(pointer) {}
    void clone(Base* pointer) override
    {
        B* pointa = (B*)pointer;
        cout << "clone B" << endl;
        //Clone Variables here
    }
};
```

This means I can now copy the objects in the following way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)listA.size(); i++)
{
    listA[i]->clone(listB[i]);
}
```

However this solution is not in any way typesafe, a requirement I want to meet. I looked into my idea, and decided to do things manually without the list, which means lot's of duplicated code, but brings peace of mind.